# Topology for ideal cutband response (-20dB per decade per order) for passive, low pass, constant output impedance filter

Tags: impedance, low-pass, passive-filter, transimpedance

I am trying to develop a low-pass constant output impedance filter.
The output impedance must be within ±10% of 5Ω from DC up to 1GHz.
The filter is driving an open load (>10M) and must filter current noise above 1kHz.

To build such a circuit, I would normally use a transimpedance amplifier with a low pass feedback.
Unfortunately, the filter must only be composed of passive (RLC) elements.

Typical low pass filters have the problem that their output impedance changes after the cut-off frequency.

My current solution requires that I must add a resistor (R2) to a LC filter (L1-C1) to prevent the capacitor from shunting my output impedance. By doing so, the frequency roll-off corresponds to a filter with half the order. i.e. in this case, -20db per decade instead of -40db per decade.

Is there a way to achieve -40dB per decade without cascading other elements? There seems to be a lack of literature on constant output impedance passive filters.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwcaVS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: Parasitics were omitted to keep the question about the topology of the filter. 
In practice, I have the ESL of C1 and the parallel capacitance of L1. These parasitics are compensated by a second LC+R stage with smaller values, which have smaller parasitics.

Comment: from where to 1 GHz do you need constant impedance? In perfection, I'm almost certain constant impedance passive networks cannot exist (aside from all-pass filters, maybe), but maybe something close enough for your application?

Comment: It's also not clear how that would help you – you want to cut off anything above 1 kHz, so: if there's no frequencies leaving your circuit >> 1 kHz, why (and how) would you even want to define an impedance?

Comment: no specs for attenuation vs f or Zin vs f? or DC source Z(f) or why no active parts?  so no solution

Comment: These specs are not realizable, as written without tolerances

Comment: Do you know about SRF in 1mH inductors? Maybe you can define the real requirements instead.

Comment: Parasitics will kill you , you need to model them. They will insert a few poles past 100MHz. Also, you will need to know what the load is for this filter to makes sense.

Comment: What is the tolerance for Zout and noise attenuation at 2kHz, 10kHz, 100kHz, 1MHz, 10MHz, 100MHz, and up? You cannot define it as  “must reject above 1kHz and 5 Ohm constant with 2nd order” without limits and tolerances.

Comment: Whereas it would be easy to use an active capacitance multiplier to create 1mF or near 1 Ohm at 1kHz and low pass filter up to desired frequency with a Zout << 1 Ohm that can pass 1A then add 5 Ohms in series... to meet your spec.  Why would you need this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get a higher rolloff is to insert additional poles.

Shown below:

- Vout (green) your filter
- Vout1 (blue) additional pole with 40dB rolloff
- Vout2 (red) your filter with parasitics (ESR and ESL on cap and ESR and capacitance on inductor)

[image]

You'll probably need to get X2Y caps an parallel them with normal caps to get the rolloff to continue at high frequencies.